# VueJS: passing object to component as prop - comes through as null

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I'm having the below issue where I pass through an object to a component as a prop, when I console.log the prop in the component it returns null. When I console log the object in the parent (root) that is passing the object, it is valid.

Can anyone spot any issues or something I'm doing wrong?

My gut tells me that **vehicle-details component** is logging **vehicle_details** before root has retrieved the data. Should I not be using mounted for this or should I be taking a different approach?

Thanks.

**index.html** - *see vehicle-details component*

```
<div id="app">

    <form-wizard color="#64c5b1" error-color="#fee5e6" ref="wizard" title="" subtitle="" v-cloak>

        <tab-content title="Dealer Details" icon="mdi mdi-account-check" :before-change="() => validate('DealerDetails')" :before-change="beforeTabSwitch">

            <div class="card-box ribbon-box">
                <div class="ribbon ribbon-custom">
                    Dealer Details
                </div>

                <dealer-details ref="DealerDetails" @on-validate="onStepValidate"></dealer-details>

            </div>

        </tab-content>

        <tab-content title="Vehicle Details" icon="mdi mdi-car-wash" :before-change="() => validate('VehicleDetails')">

            <div class="card-box ribbon-box">
                <div class="ribbon ribbon-custom">
                    Vehicle Details
                </div>

                <!-- Object below is valid, data is expected -->
                {{vehicle_details}}
                <!--  Passing through vehicle_details object to component, comes through as null on the other end -->
                <vehicle-details ref="VehicleDetails" @on-validate="onStepValidate" v-bind:vehicle_details="vehicle_details"></vehicle-details>

            </div>

        </tab-content>

    </form-wizard>

</div>
```

**root** - *see mounted section where retrieving vehicle_details*

```
import DealerDetails from '/vuejs/DealerDetails.js'
import VehicleDetails from '/vuejs/VehicleDetails.js'

Vue.use(VueFormWizard);

new Vue({
    el:'#app',
    data() {
        return {
            vehicle_details: null
        };
    },
    components: {
        DealerDetails,
        VehicleDetails
    },
    methods: {
        validate(ref) {
            return this.$refs[ref].validate();
        },
        onStepValidate(validated, model) {
            if (validated) {
                this.finalModel = { ...this.finalModel, ...model };
            }
        }
    },
    mounted: function() {
        let self = this;

        var page_url = window.location.pathname;
        var job_id = page_url.split("/")[4];
        if(job_id != null) {
            $.get('myurl/' + job_id, function(data) {

                data = $.parseJSON(data);

                self.vehicle_details = {
                    vehicle_model_id: data.jobDetails.vehicle_model_id
                };

                // Object below is valid, data is expected
                console.log(self.vehicle_details);

            });
        }
    }
});
```

**vehicle-details component** - see mounted section where logging vehicle_details - returns null

```
import Bus from '/vuejs/Bus.js'

export default {
    name: 'vehicle-details',
    props: {
        vehicle_details: {
            type: Object,
            default: null
        }
    },
    data() {
        return {
            vehicle_model: null
        };
    },
    mounted: function() {
        // Below logs null 
        console.log(this.vehicle_details);
    },
    methods: {
        validate() {
            // todo: validation
            this.error = false;
            return true;
        }
    },
    watch: {
        // Emit vehicle model changes so other components can access it
        vehicle_model: function() {
            Bus.$emit('vehicle-model', this.vehicle_model);
        }
    },
    template: `
             <div class="col-xs-12">

                <p>
                    <h5 class="card-title">Please provide details for the effected vehicle</h5>
                </p>

                <hr/>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-2 col-form-label">Vehicle Model</label>
                    <div class="col-10">
                        <input type="text" v-model="vehicle_model" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>

             </div>
  `,
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data is null when you create, and this is propagated to the child component's property when `mounted`.

Only after the async call returns does the member get set.  At that time, only reactive listeners will be updated. `mounted` has already been called, and will not be called again.

To react to this update from a 'non template' attribute, add a `watcher`.

```
watchers:{
    vehicle_details(value){
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow thank you that has worked, a lot easier than moving to emit.